# Call a function only once and let other functions access it's return value?

Tags: c

I have a function that writes logs to the log file - `write_log()`.

I need to know what type of disk I am dealing with, SSD or traditional HDD. I have a function for that:

```
/*
 * Returns disk type.
 *
 *  0 -> SSD
 *  1 -> HDD
 */
int get_disk_type(void)
{
    int disk_type;
    char line[line_buf];
    FILE * disk_pipe = fopen("/sys/block/sda/queue/rotational", "r");

    if(disk_pipe)
    {
        fgets(line, sizeof line, disk_pipe);
        sscanf(line, "%d", &disk_type);
    }

    fclose(disk_pipe);
    return disk_type;
}
```

I thought of passing `disk_type` as an argument to the function that logs the messages to the log file. Since the function is being called too many times it is impossible to change the syntax of `write_log()` everywhere.

I thought maybe let `write_log()` call `get_disk_type()` but since `write_log()` is being called too many times, `get_disk_type()` will be called several times too and that might hinder the performance (this has been confirmed from the log file).

So I was wondering what's the best way for the `write_log()` to access `disk_type`?

Comment: `popen("cat ...")`? Why not just `fopen("...")`?

Comment: @melpomene Yea right. Will update it.

Comment: Changing calls to `write_log()` everywhere is easy with a refactoring IDE (or global regex search/replace).

Comment: I think maybe inside of write_log put disk type in a static int instead, that way get_disk_type always returns correct value and you can choose what to do with it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could cache the value of `disk_type` in a static variable, since it should not change while the program is running:

```
int get_disk_type(void)
{
    static int disk_type = -1;
    if(disk_type >= 0)
        return disk_type;
    // disk type not known yet, check
    char line[line_buf];
    FILE * disk_pipe = popen("cat /sys/block/sda/queue/rotational", "r");

    if(disk_pipe)
    {
        fgets(line, sizeof line, disk_pipe);
        sscanf(line, "%d", &disk_type);
    }

    pclose(disk_pipe);
    return disk_type;
}
```

Comment: You can call `get_disk_type` from `write_log`, because it it very fast when it has cached the value.

Comment: Only the first call to `get_disk_type` will do the work, subsequent calls will just return the previous value.

Answer (score 0):

If the issue here is that the file access within get_disk_type is too slow, you can consider caching its return value like this:

```
int get_disk_type(void)
{
    static int disk_type = 2;

    if(2 == disk_type)
    {
        char line[line_buf];
        FILE * disk_pipe = popen("cat /sys/block/sda/queue/rotational", "r");
        if(disk_pipe)
        {
            fgets(line, sizeof line, disk_pipe);
            sscanf(line, "%d", &disk_type);
        }

        pclose(disk_pipe);
    }
    return disk_type;
}
```

Here I used "2" simply because it's a value your comment said couldn't be returned, so it serves as an "invalid" token. The use of "static" means that this variable persists between function calls. Therefore the file accesses will only occur the first time this function is called.

Comment: Same as @alain's answer, except for yuor choice of initial value.

Comment: Yes, he beat me to it.